# Pandas intersect multiple series based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of `pandas.core.series.Series`. The size of list is 10. Each series in the list has an index and a value.

I want to intersect the 10 `pandas.core.series.Series` in the list to obtain one final DataFrame of all values with common index as the new index. It should have 10 columns for values corresponding to elements in the original list.

Is there a pythonic way to do this instead of using series intersection multiple times?

Comment: Please provide a sample and desired data sets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the list of series `los`

```
los = [
    pd.Series([1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4], name='A'),
    pd.Series([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], name='B'),
    pd.Series([1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 2], name='C')
]
```

Using `pd.concat` with parameter `join='inner'`
`'inner'` is required to get the intersection of indices

```
pd.concat(los, axis=1, join='inner')

   A  B  C
4  3  3  1
2  2  2  3
```

---

Had we not used `join='inner'`

```
pd.concat(los, axis=1)

     A    B    C
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  1.0  NaN
2  2.0  2.0  3.0
3  NaN  NaN  2.0
4  3.0  3.0  1.0
```

Which is ***not*** the intersection

Answer (score 1):

The command `pd.concat` is intended specifically for this. Note that, in my example, the indexes are all the same but `pd.concat` will intersect indexes automatically.

```
## generate data
series_list = [pd.Series(np.random.randn(10)) for x in range(10)]

## output example
In [13]: pd.concat(series_list, axis=1)
Out[13]:
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0  0.859256 -2.283672  0.539067 -0.745864 -2.658162  0.353576  0.482614
1  0.999823  0.155528 -0.579598  0.356863 -0.135860 -0.406351  0.888127
2 -0.727666 -1.571515  0.639486  0.394803  0.478038  0.244531 -1.422910
3  0.582662  1.469884 -3.337026 -0.407253 -2.351327 -0.676233  0.018020
4  1.173179  0.211506 -0.360274 -0.299976 -0.479131  1.735279  0.549555
5 -1.589117 -2.037131 -1.843098  0.066606  0.166258 -1.444472  1.534016
6 -0.275819 -0.978669  2.299632  0.807746 -1.358762  1.190374 -0.668204
7  0.933350 -0.536032  1.285759  0.677269 -0.385078 -0.357661  2.085237
8  0.167977  0.090950  1.220945  1.085571 -0.486978  0.848816 -0.559023
9 -1.006001 -0.168631  1.501675 -0.351409  1.719402  0.337982 -0.776788

          7         8         9
0  0.015773  2.356775 -1.288013
1  1.292615  1.272147  0.347335
2  1.410002 -0.364822 -0.372589
3 -2.306940 -0.816853  2.565389
4 -1.815764 -1.547376  1.104517
5 -1.561681 -0.373882  0.582264
6 -1.272563 -0.317298 -0.446855
7  1.179011 -1.402293  0.424124
8 -1.839095  1.278204 -1.166991
9  0.950620  0.681596 -1.908053
```